# UFT checkpoint failing, even though actual & expected match

Tags: hp-uft

I'm still pretty new with UFT. I've run into a curious issue with the checkpoints.
Part of the test I'm writing hits a webpage, clicks 'add' and add a name. I have the name stored as a parameter in my datasheet. I have a checkpoint setup to be the same parameter. However, when looking at the test report it keeps failing on that checkpoint. The actual vs expected are identical, but it fails every time. Anyone else ever come across this?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the report? perhaps there's a hard to see difference (changes in whitespaces etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If its not bitmap check point then better you use GetRoProperty to fetch the property out of object and comparing it with the expected one.